# How to know which cognito user is triggering lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

Is there a way to determine which user from a Cognito user pool is triggering a lambda function through the API Gateway? I am making a simple web app with a python backend that runs on lambda. I need to know the "sub UUID" of the Cognito user who triggered the function in order to show them the appropriate information from my DynamoDB database. Is there a way to know who triggered the function when they do so while signed in to Cognito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of a JWT token that stores information about the particular user within it. Here's one way to do this:

1. When you create the Cognito user, save their sub UUID in your DynamoDB table, setting the UUID as the primary key
2. When the user first logs in, use the Cognito API to authenticate them. If successful then you can see the data Cognito has about them, including their UUID
3. Save this UUID inside of a JWT token (you can use the [pyjwt](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/) library to do this if you're using python)
4. Set a HTTP Only cookie for the user containing the JWT
5. Now whenever a user makes a request to your API Gateway and they're authenticated you can extract the cookie that was sent along with the request inside of your Lambda function
6. Validate the JWT to make sure it's genuine and hasn't been tampered with
7. Extract the UUID property from the JWT
8. Use the UUID to query your DynamoDB table for your particular user, and then show them the appropriate information

This is just one way of doing this. You can also use sessions or store JWTs in the browser's localStorage (although you should consider the security risks of doing so).